# error using g_idle_add() in C++, same thing works in C

Tags: c, gstreamer, glib, gobject

I need to use `g_idle_add()` in a `C++` code, where a `GSourceFunc` is another class function and have to pass some arguments also. Have seen its  use in C code only. So may be I am not getting the things right

While using `g_idle_add()` in a C code is straight forward

**C program**

> g_idle_add ((GSourceFunc) functionA, someData);

where *functionA* is a function defined in that C program file scope and *someData* is a structure

**C++ program**

> g_idle_add ((GSourceFunc) (mObjOfAnotherClass->functionB (*
>   p_SomeVariable)), NULL)

Also, consider the scenario where I have to pass more than one arguments to functionB

The difference here is about the scope of functions called from g_idle_add. Can I call the g_idle_add() like I have done above in sample C++ code

Answer (score 2):

A pointer to a function is different than a pointer to a class method. You have to have an object of the class if you want to use a pointer to a method. You should wrap your method in a C function. For example:

```
extern "C"
{
    void myCFunction(void *p_SomeVariable)
    {
        // store your object where you want 
        static AnotherClass    mObjOfAnotherClass; 
        mObjOfAnotherClass.functionB(*p_SomeVariable);  
    }
}
```

And then:

```
g_idle_add ((GSourceFunc) myCFunction, p_SomeVariable);
```

Comment: Thanks, What if I have to pass more than one arguments in functionB

Comment: In this case, you should pass a structure to `functionB` (and to `myCFunction` too so), which will contain all the needed data.